# How to be permanently scentless?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, tracking

I really like the effect that [deodorizing agent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances#TOC-Deodorizing-Agent) provides and have been wondering how to get it as a permanent effect.

> Coating a creature in a vial of this milky, odorless substance takes 1 minute and renders it scentless for 1d3 hours. Creatures that rely on scent for locating creatures do not gain the benefit of this ability against a creature affected by a dose of deodorizing agent.

So my understanding of the ability is that scent can't be used to find me, so if I'm invisible my square/hex can't be found, and I can't be tracked over distances by scent.

I don't know of any process which allows you to creating lasting alchemical effects (if you know of any please let me know), so I started looking at spells.

I came across [*pass without trace*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/pass-without-trace) which seems to meet my needs

> The subject or subjects of this spell do not leave footprints or a scent trail while moving. Tracking the subjects is impossible by non-magical means.

The not leaving footprints is a nice bonus, but I want to make sure that not being track-able also applies to if I was invisible. If so then this spell would make a wonderful boot magic item.

Does *pass without trace* have the effect I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Negate Aroma](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/negate-aroma) (Druid 1 spell) does exactly what you ask for.

> A creature under the effect of negate aroma cannot be tracked, located, or pinpointed by the scent special quality.

Pass Without Trace probably doesn't hide you from realtime perception by some creature with scent who's standing next to you. But the only evidence I can give for this conclusion is: If it did, then Negate Aroma would be redundant.

Comment: Well, a similar conclusion to "you don't leave a scent trail but you can still be scented by someone who is present" would be "you don't leave footprints but if someone touches your foot they can still feel it". Which seems pretty reasonable. Pass Without Trace specifically says that it prevents you leaving behind (two kinds of) evidence of having been there, and specifically doesn't say *how* it achieves that. If it made you odourless or your feet intangible then you'd think they'd mention that :-)

Comment: And another spell of the same name in a related game (https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/pass-without-trace) *does* make you harder to detect in person. So again, if the Pathfinder version is supposed to make you harder to detect by scent in person then it really ought to say so...

Answer (score 5):

### An effect like the spell [*pass without trace*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/pass-without-trace) may be insufficient to conceal totally a creature from [scent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Scent)…

You've quoted the whole spell, so [*pass without trace*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/passWithoutTrace.html#pass-without-trace) does *only* that. Ask the GM to be sure, but a strict reading could mean, for example, a creature nonetheless leaves evidence of its passing—including its odor—in squares it occupies at the end of any movement that isn't immediately followed by *more* movement (or something; the spell's not 100% clear). While that's a highly technical reading, the spell *is* called ***pass*** without trace not ***camp*** without trace. So, to be certain, [as topquark suggests](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84253/8610), you really want the spell [*negate aroma*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/negate-aroma).

Although not listed among the possibilities for the spell [*permanency*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency), "[t]he GM may allow other spells to be made permanent," and, as 1st-level spells, each of [*negate aroma*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/negate-aroma) and [*pass without trace*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/pass-without-trace), if allowed, should cost only 2,500 gp plus 1,000 gp each to hire a level 20 wizard for the [spellcasting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/hirelings-servants-services#TOC-Spellcasting) involved. You could get both and be doubly sure.

#### …But some magic items negate [scent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Scent) continuously

There are two that I'm aware of.

- The [*cloak of the hunt*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic-items/other-magic-items) (*Mythic Adventures* 150) (12,000 gp; 1 lb.), among other (sometimes mythic) effects, "renders the wearer immune to the scent ability."
- An animal wearing the [*pull-ring of scent*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pull-ring-of-scent) (*Animal Archive* 26) (11,000 gp; 1 lb.), among other effects, causes the animal "(and its rider, if any) [to give] no scent and [makes it so they] cannot be tracked or located by scent."

You may be able to save 1,000 gp by buying the *pull-ring* yet *not* also ride a [mastadon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/elephant/elephant-mastodon) by sticking that *pull-ring of scent* through your *own* nose and 1/hour making a [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device) skill check to emulate a race (DC 25) to receive the *pull-ring*'s benefits yourself by convincing the *pull-ring* you're a [giraffe](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/herd-animals/herd-animal-giraffe) or a [platypus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/platypus) or whatever. However, because the skill Use Magic Device is *already* pretty boss—and this *is* pretty silly—, this may not fly, and, even if it does, the GM may require the player to periodically make appropriate animal noises. You may find using the *cloak of the hunt* more dignified.

Comment: I did not know about the mythic items. This character has no UMD skill and no Cha so wont be faking out any magic items. The Permanency is an interesting thought to get around having it as an item

Answer (score 0):

If you are an alchemist, you can use the [Eternal Potion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/eternal-potion) discovery on a [Negate Aroma](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/negate-aroma) potion. You can do it with a potion of Pass without Trace too, but not at the same time (and it won't conceal you from scent, as HeyI noted).